# Simulink Scope data not accessible after running the sim() command

Tags: matlab, scope, simulink

I am running a [Simulink](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/)  model from the command line using the [sim()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/using-the-sim-command.html) command. I also activated the  [Save data to workspace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/rtwin/ug/logging-signals-to-the-base-workspace.html) in my scopes. The simulation runs without problems but the variables are not saved by the scope. Note that if I start the simulation using the play button from my simulink model, data is saved to the workspace.

Comment: How do you call the `sim` command? Simply with `sim(my_model)` or with an output argument, such as `SimOut = sim(my_model);`?

Comment: @am304, I tried both of them. With `SimOut = sim(my_model)` , the variable `SimOut` is created but it's empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment from @am304 gave me a start point. 
One has to use

```
SimOut = sim(my_model);
x=SimOut.get('VariableName')
```

and problem solved